# Controlling 3 phase motor in both directions

Tags: c++, stm32

I'm currently working on a project (using P-NUCLEO-IHM03 motor-control Nucleo pack) where I'm trying to control a motor in both directions. However, when switching from one direction to another, there is a delay which I would like to remove.

Using MC API here is my current code:

```
MC_ProgramSpeedRampMotor1(700/6, 3000);
MC_StartMotor1();
HAL_DELAY(8000);
MC_STopMotor1();
HAL_DELAY(2000);
 
MC_ProgramSpeedRampMotor1(-700/6, 3000);
MC_StartMotor1();
HAL_DELAY(8000);
MC_STopMotor1();
HAL_DELAY(2000);
```

As you can see, after stopping the motor, I need to add a delay before starting it again in the opposite direction. However, I would like to switch between the two directions immediately without any delay.

I'm aware that the motor needs a start-up time to begin rotating, but I'm wondering if there is a way to switch between the two directions directly without any delay. Note: If I remove the delay of 2000ms then the motor won't switch its direction.

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, please let me know. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Not familiar with MC API myself – but I'd at very first look up if there's a function you can use to test if the motor is ready again to be restarted. That would allow minimising the delay between stopping and starting as much as possible. Otherwise I'd start minimising manually (2000, 1000, 500 and if 500 stops working reliably I'd go on with 750, if working again 625, etc – halving the respective intervals until interval between working and not working is appropriately small, maybe 10 or 5 ms?).

Comment: Are you sure this is a software problem? A not uncommon problem with motors is that they can create power surges or dips which cause microcontrollers to reboot. When it suddenly changes direction it will use more power than when it starts from a standstill. Maybe you could test this by putting a delay or flashing an LED when the microcontroller starts up.

Comment: @user253751 Good point – *'If I remove the delay of 2000ms then the motor won't switch its direction.'* would clearly match this issue...

Comment: @user253751 yes I tried to run the motor with a simplefoc and in arduino and it worked fine. There I could switch motor directions instantly without delays. However, when using P-NUCLEO-IHM03 pack and MC API, I needed to set a delay for the switch.

Comment: Can you reduce the delay and it still works? What's the magic number? Do a binary search.